# A limit theorem for markov chain on $[0,1]$

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains

$f_1, f_2,\dots f_m$ are continuous maps on $[0,1]\to [0,1]$ and they form a Markov chain as follows $X_{n+1}= f_{\omega_n}(X_n)$ where $\omega_0, \dots, \omega_n$ are i.i.d discrete random variables taking values in $\{1,2,\dots,m\}$. We are given that there is an unique invariant measure for the above system and also $|X_n(x, \omega)-X_n(y, \omega)|\to 0$ almost surely as $n\to \infty$, where $X_n(x,\omega)$ is a realization of the chain starting from a point $x$. Could anyone tell me how to show $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n+1}\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}f(X_k(x,\omega))\to \int f d\mu$ for all continuous function $f$ for all $x$ and for almost all $\omega$.

I started with $x=X_0\sim \mu$ then $X_n=(f_{\omega_{n-1}}\circ f_{\omega_{n-2}}\circ\cdots\circ f_{\omega_0})(X_0)= X_n(x, \omega)$ right?

Comment: Define $T:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$ by $(Tg)(x) = E g(f_\omega(x))$ where $\omega$ is distributed as $\omega_n$.  I would try to show that for each continuous $g$ the set $\{T^n g: n\in\mathbb N\}$ is equicontinuous, that is, your chain is an "e-chain".

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will be waiting to see your detail explanation, in the meantime may I ask you whether the result is true for any complete separable metric space?

Comment: I have no idea what is e-chain though...but I know the definition of an equicontinuous family of function.

Comment: It's all explained in Meyn and Tweedie's 1993 book, _Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability_.

Comment: I have no such books

Comment: Try http://probability.ca/MT/BOOK.pdf .

Comment: which page/section/chapters if you tell me?